# Bike lookup: Is this the bike I ordered or a women's model?

Tags: mountain-bike, specialized-bikes

I just received the bike I ordered last week and it looks much different from the 2018 model that I tried at my local bike shop.

I ordered the latest model of "Specialized Rockhopper Base" but the top tube is so much lower. The bike shop employee said they changed the frame for this year and I can't find any reference for a bike with this geometry on the [Specialized website](https://www.specialized.com/us/en/search?q=rockhopper%3Arelevance%3Aarchived%3Atrue%3AisBike%3Atrue). I feel like this is a women's bike and they are tricking me.

I appreciate any help or advice.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This used to be called a "mixte" -- halfway between a standard diamond men's frame and a traditional "women's" frame.  It was popular for BMX and mountain bikes at one point, a selling point being that you could easily straddle it, even in unstable footing conditions.

Comment: (Hint:  Women's frames are a different color.)

Comment: The 2018 bike I tried for at the store had a straight top tube. I feel this is too small. The other one was also medium. I am confused.

Comment: That is common MTB geometry ans has been for a while. Check for the specification of components to see if your bike component match. I've seen many cases where a "woman's" bike uses exactlty the same frame as the "men's" model and different (lower) spec components. (As in less gears, less powerful brakes, less suspension travel)

Comment: @DanielRHicks you beat me to it, I was going to say it can't be women's because it's not pink (funny cos it's true? shame)

Comment: `20 Rockhoppers have sloping top tubes, but it does look small.There should be a sticker on the seat tube or down tube identifying the frame size.

Comment: Is it comfortable for you when you ride ?   If so, gender is irrelevant.

Comment: @Criggie it's too small. My knees hurt when I ride it.

Comment: @Node.JS then your saddle is too low.  Suggests the frame is too small if you can't raise the saddle to a suitable height.  Gender is irrelevant to your personal leg length.

Comment: Certainly not a 21 speed (I assume that’s what “21 SP“ stands for).

Comment: I'll note that the bike is pretty much identical (save for color) to this Specialized Pitch 27.5 MTB:  https://ibkbike.com/trail-mountain-bikes/specialized-pitch/pitch-275-mtb-specialized-2020-gloss-mint-oak-green#/350-size-xl

Comment: The "M" on your ticket implies that it's a "medium", suitable for someone between 5-5 and 5-10 (see sizing guide in ibkbike link above).

Comment: (And the Specialized Pitch is a 16-speed.)

Answer (score 6):

As Swifty said Specialized does not have men's or women's bikes starting with the 2020 model year. [Here is a link to their hyper buzz worded article](https://www.specialized.com/us/en/beyond-gender) on the topic "BEYOND GENDER".

To illustrate the truth of no more genders go to the [website for Specialized shopping for Rockhoppers](https://www.specialized.com/us/en/shop/bikes/c/bikes?q=%3Arelevance%3Aarchived%3Atrue%3AisBike%3Atrue%3AproductFamily%3ARockhopper&sort=price-desc)

1. Filter for MODEL YEAR 2019
2. Notice that men's bikes and women's bikes are listed.
3. Remove the filter for MODEL YEAR = 2019
4. Filter for MODEL YEAR = 2020
5. Notice that the gender qualifier is missing from the bike names in the results.
6. Leaving the MODEL YEAR filter set to 2020, flip the GENDER filter back and forth between Men and Women.
7. Notice that the same bikes are in either Men or Women, or both.

No "Men's Rockhopper" or "Women's Rockhopper" only "Rockhopper" for 2020

At the bike shop you must have tried a different model or year of Rockhopper.
According to the sizing chart from an authorized Specialized dealer:
[image]

If you are 5'6" to 5'10" you would ride a medium.
If you are in the range for the size of bike you have I'd take it back to the shop and have them fit the bike to you.

No matter what the chart says if you are unhappy with the size you can exchange it.

Specialized has a 30 day return policy
From the [Specialized FAQ](https://www.specialized.com/us/en/faq):

> Can I exchange an item if it doesn't fit?
>
> We realize that buying items that are size-specific over the internet is difficult. Because of that, we offer a 30-day satisfaction guarantee on products purchased from our webstore.
> Upon receiving your order, if you find the need to exchange an item for the same item in a different size or color, we can help. However, if you want to switch to a different item, then you'll need to return the item for a refund and order the new item separately.
> We will send out the replacement item(s) on exchanges within five days of receiving the original item back. We will send it via Fed-Ex 2-Day air, at no charge to you, to the address from the original order.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I returned that bike and I got a Haro mountain bike. It's more expensive but well worth it.

Comment: I said it, but you said it better!

Answer (score 3):

Apparently Specialized have stopped making women's specific bikes, see [article](https://www.cyclesuk.com/content/specialized-to-stop-making-women-s-specific-bikes.aspx) and indeed I found no women's bikes on their [website](https://www.specializedconceptstore.co.uk). Your bike is therefore not a women's specific bike, it is a unisex bike.

The frame geometry doesn't look exactly like the Rockhopper ones on the website, but they will only feature certain sizes in the photoshoots. I wonder if larger ones have a different angle on the tubing to your medium frame but I don't know. I see no reason to mistrust the bike shop people, they know the latest and would get a bad reputation quickly if they were lying to customers.

Manufacturers make changes to things like frame geometry all the time so they have a new product to sell.

Comment: I found several bikes labeled "women's" (and a similar number labeled "men's") on the Specialized site.

Comment: But, yeah, I do suspect that this bike is a "shorter" one than the ones shown in the catalog.

Comment: @DanielRHicks hurr, I can't find something definitive to say it's not women's lol, how do you prove a negative again? The only bikes labelled women's or men's I found were old (2019, 2018) models, on sale as old stock; I went through all the mountain bikes and road bikes on concept store website. But I'm not finding it easy, they seem to have multiple websites and varied ways of displaying similar information. Would be definitive if someone found a statement type page saying "all our bikes are unisex since year 20xx"!